# Constructor call sequence

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, language-lawyer, virtual-inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
class A {};

class B : virtual public A {};

class C : virtual public A {};

class D : public B, public C {};

D d;
```

The Visual Studio's compiler first calls the constructor of class B, then the constructor of class C. But is this a Rule, i.e. does the ISO C++ standard guarantee the order of constructor call?

Comment: @Holt: It's _obviously_ not...?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They are related; being `virtual` does not change the situation. But I do consider the answer given in this Question more clear than in the other one.

Comment: Eduard, the `virtual` portion of the above question is irrelevant to the answer.  Do you mind if we eliminate it from the question, so that this question is more universally applicable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's guaranteed. From §12.6.2 [class.base.init]/p11 of N3797:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class *base-specifier-list*.
> - Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the *base-specifier-list* (regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).

Comment: This answer is, in my opinion, much clearer than the flagged-for-duplicate answers.